# Como permitir el acceso a una web con .htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

tengo 2 paginas web asi

Ejemplo:
Dominio1.com (hosting1.es)  (de aca enlazo a dominio2.net y extraigo informacion)
Dominio2.net (hostinger.com) (de aca tengo el archivo .htacces)

tengo mi archivo .htaccess en dominio2.net cual esta de esta formaa continuacion:

```
order allow,deny
deny from all
allow from 192.168.200.14 (Si funciona para ip personal)
allow from Dominio1.com  (No funciona ni con la ip del dominio)
```

Lo que quiero lograr es denegar el acceso a todo el mundo y solamente permitir el acceso a unas ips y a Dominio1.com, el problema es que no me funciona y me sigue denegando el acceso a Dominio1.com tambien intente hacerle ping y colocar la ip que me arrojo pero nada igual no me funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allow from HOSTNAME` no funciona como se espera en .htaccess

Apache comprueba por DNS reverso (es decir, toma la ip actual y ejecuta una consulta reversa por IP para obtener el nombre de host), y generalmente este es un host diferente al que ingresas:

Por ejemplo

```
www.google.com -> 172.217.3.164 (DNS normal)
172.217.3.164 -> sea15s11-in-f4.1e100.net (DNS reverso)
```

Por lo que no tendra el resultado esperado. Debes averiguar la IP publica del servidor que se conecta al servicio y usar esta IP. Si tiene multiples IPs puedes usar el rango de IP o subnet (IP/mask), por ejemplo

```
Allow from 10.0.0.0/24
Allow from 10.1.0.0/255.255.0.0
```

Existe una opcion que es mas reciente pero no he probado aun, usando la directiva

`Require forward-dns HOSTNAME`
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html#requiredirectives

Si usas PHP puedes comprobar el origen usando las variables de servidor:

```
$IP=$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$HOST_IPS= gethostbynamel("hostname.com");
if (in_array($IP,$HOST_IPS)){
    // host ok
}
```

En muchos casos, el hosting tiene desactivado las consultas a DNS y muchas veces no tienen respuesta. Puedes revisar si es el caso tambien.

Comment: Gracias amigo, me meti en el hosting directo en cpanel, y ahi vi el dominio que manejan en esa parte, le hice un ping y me arrojo la ip correcta la que buscaba gracias!